# How to extract all the text from a webpage?

Tags: java, html, dom, web, jsoup

I am using JSoup library to extract texts in webpages. Following is my code

```
 Document doc;

try {
 URL url = new URL(text);


 doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 70000);

 Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
 for(Element p : paragraphs)
 {

    textField.append(p.text());
    textField.append("\n");
 }
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{

   ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

Here, I am only able to get text from "p" tags. But I need all the texts in the page. How can I do it? That might be by looping through nodes, but I just started using `JSoup`.

Comment: Have edited my answer, let me know if any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String text = Jsoup.parse(new URL("https://www.google.com"), 10000).text();
System.out.println(text);
```

Here, 10000 is in milliseconds and refers to timeout.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. Anyway, it seems like not extracting text from wikipadia and all

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence I have used it for extracting text from Wikipedia , but may be my requirement is different. For example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29 , i have used this url in above code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/), because you don't need HTML parsing, but only text extraction. This should be faster and less CPU-consuming.

*Example:*

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/some-location/index.html");
// NOTE: Use ArticleExtractor unless DefaultExtractor gives better results for you
String text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
```

Taken from: https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/wiki/QuickStart

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a different approach entirely. I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, thus I don't know exactly what you need. But you could grab the entire raw source of the entire web page. Then use regexp to delete all of the html tags. I did something similar (though in php) for a text to code ratio tool once.